# Filtrar valores específicos de uma variável

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Eu tenho um conjunto de dados e gostaria de filtrar alguns valores da variável `y`. Por exemplo, de 0 a 0.3 e o valor de 1. Tenho usado o `filter` do `dplyr` e não consegui.

```
x <- c(6, 3, 7, 2, 7, 9)

y <- c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 1)

d <- data.frame(x, y)

d %>%
 filter(y == 1, y <= 0.3)
```

Comment: Porquê o voto para baixo? A pergunta tem uma descrição do problema, dados e o código da tentativa de solução. O código estar errado *não* é motivo para votos negativos, se estivesse certo não era preciso perguntar, não é?

Answer (score 3):

No seu código você está fazendo o mesmo que:

```
d %>%
 filter(y == 1.0) %>%
 filter(y <= 0.3)
```

Assim, não sobrará nenhuma observação. Você precisa usar o operador `|`, que implica na operação *OU*.

```
d %>%
  filter(y == 1 | y <= 0.3)
```

E ainda se desejar adicionar a condição maior que 0, seria:

```
d %>%
  filter(y == 1 | (y >= 0 & y <= 0.3))
```

ou utilizando `between`

```
d %>%
  filter(y == 1 | between(y,0,0.3))
```

Comment: Eu tenho feito também um gráfico mas ele ficou com os valores vazios no meio, como nesse gráfico que adicionei a minha pergunta. Eu queria saber se posso cortar o eixo do X de 0.25 até 0.9.

Comment: @JeanneFranco eu não vi o gráfico, mas se estiver utilizando o `ggplot2` a partir do comando `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(.25,.90))` seria possível